# PHP and Apache Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess file

```
Options -Multiviews
# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Rewrite for index.php php file
RewriteRule ^welcome index.php [NC,L]

#Rewrite for index.php php file with parameters
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)$  index.php?action=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [QSA,L]
```

First i'm rewrite **index.php** to **welcome**. The problem is that when you click a button on the index.php page some variables are sent via GET to **example.php** page and soon after returned to the **index.php** like this

**Example.php page**

[...]

```
header('Location: http://example.com/welcome/added/' . $id . '/' . $name);

[welcome = index.php]
[added =  1º GET parameter]
[$id = 2º GET parameter]
[$name = 3º GET parameter]
```

**index.php page script**

```
if($action=='added'){
var_dump($_GET);

}
```

**But is return**

```
array(0) { }
```

If i change the script `header('Location: http://example.com/welcome/added/' . $id . '/' . $name);`  to `header('Location: http://example.com/index.php?action=added&id=5&name=my-string-returned);`

**The returned array are ok**

```
array(3) { ["action"]=> string(5) "added" ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["name"]=> string(20) "my-string-returned" }
```

What's wrong with my .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This rule is not what you want for three reasons:

```
RewriteRule ^welcome index.php [NC,L]
```

First, it matches all of the following:

```
welcome
welcome/blah
welcome.php
welcome/blah/12/blee/?whatever=42
```

Second, it replaces all of them with exactly

```
index.php
```

Notice there are no GET parameters, just like you see.

Third, it [L] means "last", i.e., don't do any more processing. Which is not going to work for you since you appear to want to rewrite the GET parameters using another rule.

Try this (but I haven't tested it myself):

```
RewriteRule ^welcome\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)$  index.php?action=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Ok Dwayne, thanks, but as I should write my .htaccess to match with what I want, can you help me?

Comment: could someone help me?